# Property 'campanha' does not exist on type 'DisputaComponent[]' - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, oop, typescript, observable

I'm trying to access a property inside an object called `disputas` but I'm getting this message:

> [ts] Property 'campanha' does not exist on type 'DisputaComponent[]'

I can't access any property inside `disputas`, I think it's because its returning an Array of `disputas`, so how can I access each object `disputa` inside this array?

What I'm trying to do is show only objects with the same ID of the page, here's the snippet code:

```
constructor(service: DisputaService, private route:ActivatedRoute, 
private router:Router, private campanha_service:FiltroNegociacaoService){
  service
  .lista()
  .subscribe(disputas => {
    if (this.disputas.campanha.cliente_id == this.campanha.cliente_id) // this is where I get the message
       this.disputas = disputas;
    console.log("Disputas: ", disputas); 
    console.log("Campanha: ", this.campanha);
  }, erro => console.log("erro"))
}
```

and here's the full code if you guys need it:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {DisputaService} from '../services/disputas.service';
import {FiltroNegociacaoComponent} from '../../../filtra-negociacao/components/filtra-negociacao.component';
import {FiltroNegociacaoService} from '../../../filtra-negociacao/services/filtro-negociacao.service';
import {ActivatedRoute, Routes, RouterModule, Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'disputas',
  templateUrl: `disputas.component.html`,
  providers: [DisputaService, FiltroNegociacaoService]
})

export class DisputaComponent implements OnInit {
    public disputas:DisputaComponent[] = [];
    public loading = false;
    campanhas: FiltroNegociacaoComponent;
    campanha:any;
    service: DisputaService;
    name: string;
    proposta_inicial:number;
    propostas_realizadas:number = 0;
    maximo_propostas:number;
    status = {
      status_nome: ""
    }
    id:number;

    constructor(service: DisputaService, private route:ActivatedRoute, 
    private router:Router, private campanha_service:FiltroNegociacaoService){
      service
      .lista()
      .subscribe(disputas => {
        if (this.disputas.campanha.cliente_id == this.campanha.cliente_id)
        this.disputas = disputas;
        console.log("Disputas: ", disputas); 
        console.log("Campanha: ", this.campanha);
      }, erro => console.log("erro"))
    }

    ngOnInit():void{
      this.route.params.subscribe(params =>{
      let id = params['id'];
      this.campanha_service
        .buscaPorId(id)
        .subscribe(campanha => {
          this.campanha = campanha;
        },
        erro => console.log(erro));
      })
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are retrieving an array of `disputas` and trying to find the ones with the same `cliente_id` as the one in `this.campanha`. The array itself does not have this property, you should filter the array, and then set the result:

```
.subscribe((disputas: DisputaComponent[]) => {
    this.disputas = disputas.filter(
       disputa => disputa.campanha.client_id === this.campanha.cliente_id
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that removes the message but I still cant filter. It keeps returning me every `disputa` object no matter what id it has, do you know what might be happening?

Comment: Do I have to create a filter especific for this?

Comment: @RenêSilvaLima No it should work as is. Where do you check the return of the disputas?

Comment: There's a page in which I print the objects and the `console.log("Disputas: ", disputas); ` that is right bellow the `.subscribe`

Comment: Well, obviously the `disputas` variable will contain all the disputas, but the `this.disputas` will only contain the filtered ones. You can also try and add a [`filter`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/filter.html) operation from the `Observable` class, but that's technically the same

Comment: I've tried to that too, printing `this.disputas` and still returns me all objects as if its not filtered

Comment: Your code really works, I was doing something dumb on other part of the code, thank you very much man. You really helped me a lot :). Is there any articlle where I can learn a little more about filters and Observables? Thanks

Comment: Well, the `filter` used here is just a default js array function. When it comes to `Observables` I suggest browsing their api. It's well documented, and they've got an operation for almost any use-case you can think of